# Xamarin forms: AspNetCore.SignalR.Client v1.0.3, websocket transport not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, mono, asp.net-core-signalr

**Background:**

I would like to connect to my SignalR hub using Xamarin forms SignalR websocket transport.

**My setup:**

-> SignalR hub is sitting on a Windows VM. I am connecting to the VM using the iphone simulator on Mac.

-> I have created a reverse proxy rule on iis for my self hosted SignalR hub.

-> I have added an entry to my hosts file to connect to the Hub.

**What is going wrong?**

I am able to succesfully connect to the Hub however the issue is that the transport is always set to Server Sent Events. This should be using WebSocket transport.

**What have I tried?**

I have created a web client and I was able to successfully run that, initially connecting on a http request, and after negotiation the message upgraded to WebSocket.

The difference between the two connection is one is using Javascript and Websocket support on a browser, where as Xamarin forms is using a nuget package AspNetCore.SingalR.Client.

I understand on Xamarin, the connection will first try connecting using WebSocket, then Server Sent Request and if the previous two fail long polling. But as far as I understand Mono is now able to support websocket.

Xamarin client connection code (A quick write up to test that WebSocket transport works on Xamarin forms):

```
public class PriceStream
{
    readonly HubConnection connection;

    public PriceStream()
    {
         connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                            .WithUrl("https://dev.prices:5001/priceHub")
                            .Build();

          connection.On<TestObject>("ReceiveMessage", (data) =>
          {
                var priceUpdate = new PriceUpdateMessage
                {
                    ProductId = data.ProductId,
                    PriceId = data.PriceId,
                    Price = data.Price
                };

                // update price on app 
                // TODO
          });
    }

    public async Task SubscribeAsync(int productId)
    {
        // connecting here because I want to see the transprot before sending message
        await connection.StartAsync();

        await connection.SendCoreAsync("SendMessage", new[] { productId });
    }
}
```

So what am I missing that it is not able to connect using WebSocket transport?

Comment: unrelated: Why are you calling SendCoreAsync?

Comment: @davidfowl Apologies, I accidentally chose SendCoreAsync. 
See: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2239

Comment: What version of Windows are you running on and are you using IIS? WebSockets support in IIS is limited and requires configuration (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-2.1#iisiis-express-support)